# How to debug models running in Tensorflow Serving?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, custom-operator

I wanted to try my [seq2seq](https://github.com/google/seq2seq) model in Tensorflow Serving for deployment. So, I have implemented a `Custom operation` to replace a [py_func](https://github.com/google/seq2seq/blob/7f485894d412e8d81ce0e07977831865e44309ce/seq2seq/inference/beam_search.py#L90) to successfully export the python based code.

I have tested that C++ custom op in two ways.

1. Using [load_op_library](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/load_op_library)
2. Built Tensorflow serving from source

Both ways run successfully.
But, the output and accuracy differs when running in the **second** way.

I have also used some `printf()` inside the custom op implementation to debug the input and output values.

With `load_op_library`, It prints in the stdout.

With `TF Serving`, could not see any `print`s in the stdout.

1. Why does running the same code in TF Serving does not give accurate results?
2. How can I debug the values when the model is running in TF Serving (*could not see printf's results*)?
3. Is there any way to inspect the values in `SavedModel`'s `variables` files?

Comment: 1. Is the difference in results very high. Because, Tensorflow may have some indeterministic behavior related to repeated results.

Comment: 2. If the values which you want to debug are Tensors, you can pull them using Predict command

Comment: Can you please share the Custom C++ OP

Comment: @TensorflowSupport https://gist.github.com/sathyamoorthyrr/58f5147d92f8b8168c5a0d0f8b245d2e

Comment: For Point 3, I suppose you can use the Predict command to get the values of the variables by name.